# How do I deal with a difficult-to-teach coworker?

Tags: colleagues

I have a coworker who would often ask me questions relating to his work. But what I find annoying is him constantly interrupting me to finish my sentences only to get it wrong all the time.

One instance, I purposely frowned my face and told him "please listen" after about a 3-second pause. This still didn't give him any idea to just shut up and learn.

I ignored him for a particular period of time and would say "I don't know...but try this", or "how does the boss think this is possible?" while knowing fully well the task is possible.

This approach affected his performance as he got a lot of bad reviews from our boss. And in some cases, I would be asked by our boss to assist him, then telling him there isn't solution for the problem to avoid enduring the frustration would reflect poorly on my performance too.

How do I handle this coworker as ignoring him clearly does not help as I will be officially asked to help him?

Comment: What is your goal, to help him or let him hang himself?

Comment: For how long has this been going? Is he a new hire? Are you a senior?

Comment: @SandraK Yes, I am a senior by almost 2 year. This has been going on for the past one year, at least.

Comment: @RichardU I actually don't care but he has formed a habit of nagging about our boss to me. And in some cases, the boss will ask him to consult me. And when this happens, he comes to me like it's my job to take care of his incompetence. 
So even ignoring him sometimes means me being officially asked to assist.

Comment: @Boltzmann So, is your goal to help him, make him go away, or expose his ignorance to management?  Pick one, and we can answer it.

Comment: @RichardU It seems clear from context to me that OP wants this coworker to no longer be his (or her) problem.  I think OP is indifferent between this coworker being fired or simply being told that OP isn't the go-to for questions anymore.

Comment: Have you spoken to your boss about your difficulties? Ex. "Hey boss, teaching X is becoming increasingly hard because he cuts me off when I'm explaining." I wouldn't give him bad advice or tell him you don't know because in turn he might say, "Well Boltzmann said so" or "Well Boltzmann said it's not possible" and that might reflect poorly on you

Comment: @DeanMacGregor His question is how to "handle" a coworker, that isn't extricating himself.

Comment: "Shut up and learn?" Do you honestly believe that's a good teaching strategy?

Comment: @AffableAmbler I didn't not say that to him. It's a simple sentence if you don't emphasize the "shut up" part.

Comment: @Boltzmann, you are neither helping yourself nor the coworker by such behavior. Mentoring is a form of teaching and it requires some amount of patience and tact. If you "don't care" if the coworker gets fired or suceeds it means you're not ready to take on such a role. Just admit that to your boss and move on from this.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that he tries to finish your sentences means he's interested and engaged in what you're teaching him.  Assuming your goal is to turn him into a successful team member, instead of getting annoyed when he interrupts you, listen to what he's saying and try to figure out where his reasoning is coming from. Ask questions like, "What makes you think that?" and "Aren't you forgetting about...?" Try to get a sense of how his mind works and the logic he’s using to come up with these incorrect responses. It will allow you to cater your lessons accordingly.

Comment: I've actually tried those approaches. The problem here is someone who needs help but is yet to come to the reality that he needs it. It's about him convincing himself that he's smart that he always cut me short in an attempt to arrive at the answer. I don't have problem with people trying to finish up things when they get clues they need. But what I don't understand is him failing on first attempt, second one, and third one, until I manage to finish my point. Sometimes he changes the question half way into the discussion.

Comment: @BoltzBooz As I was saying earlier I think going to your boss to explain your difficulties will be the best approach. Don't give him bad advice or tell him that you don't know as that may reflect badly on you because he would say you told him so and he wouldn't be lying.

Answer (score 2):

[No Sell](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoSell) his (possibly unintentional) attempts to fluster you. Every time he interrupts you, tell him this:

> "Hang on, let's finish the current topic. We will come back to that topic later. Why don't you note it down?"

and pretend to wait until he "notes it down". Then continue talking.

If he doesn't "note it down" and instead continues talking, repeat your instruction with a [stoic](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheStoic) expression:

> "We will come back to it. Note it down."

When you are done talking, be sure to actually come back to the noted topics:

> "Alright, I think you have noted down a few points. Let's go over them now."

---

I have mentored quite a few know-it-alls myself. After a few rounds of frustration, I figured out the above trick and found it extremely effective. Since "noting down" is a lot more effort than interrupting verbally with irrelevant comments, they eventually realised that listening to me was actually a good idea!

I also observed that when "coming back", they would not actually bother asking all the questions that I thought they had noted down, perhaps because the original purpose of those "questions" had become irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to answer this question without knowing more.

How closely related are your jobs?  How connected are your work products?  Do you have other coworkers who could help this coworker?

The generic advice for any workplace problem is to **tell the boss** about the problem and **have some ideas for how to fix the problem**.

Potential fixes could be (depending on overall work situation):

Schedule a time when you're available and establish a guideline that outside of that time coworker should do something else when they have a problem.  This is highly dependent on the type of work.  If your coworkers inability to do a task puts them in a situation where there is nothing else they can do, your boss is unlikely to go for this.

Incorporate other coworkers into helping the problem coworker so that you're not shouldering 100% of the burden.  Obviously, this is dependent on their being other people who can help.  If it's just the two of you that do your "type" of work then this isn't going to apply.

Have more work assigned directly to you if it is beyond the scope of what coworker can reasonably do.  If helping the coworker takes more time than it would take to just do the work then tell your boss that.